# div and span instead of tables

Tags: html, css

I used to have a table. A collection of one or more rows build a group (category) and get a special background color. Each cell of the row is a product to display. Each product should have a headline (name of the product) and a footer with a quantity to order.

Now I need to get this available for mobile devices.

The product pictures are 100x100 in a box (fix size).

If the screen of the mobile device gets to narrow, then the 4 products of each row should flow into 2x2 or even 4x1. This I cannot manage with tables anymore.

I tried:

```
    <div style="background-color:blue">
    <h3>Drinks</h3>
    <span class="box">
        one<br />
        <img src="notexist.gif" width="100" height="100"><br />
        Quantity: <input type='number' size='3' id='numberinput' name='mynumber' value='0' /></span>

    <span class="box">
        two<br />
        <img src="notexist.gif" width="100" height="100"><br />
        Quantity: <input type='number' size='3' id='numberinput' name='mynumber' value='0' /></span>

    <span class="box">
        three<br />
        <img src="notexist.gif" width="100" height="100"><br />
        Quantity: <input type='number' size='3' id='numberinput' name='mynumber' value='0' /></span>
</div>
<div>
    <table>
        <tr bgcolor="purple">
        <td>one<br />
            <img src="notexist.gif" width="100" height="100"><br />
            Quantity: <input type='number' size='3' id='numberinput' name='mynumber' value='0' /></span>
        <td>two<br />
            <img src="notexist.gif" width="100" height="100"><br />
            Quantity: <input type='number' size='3' id='numberinput' name='mynumber' value='0' /></span>
        <td>three<br />
            <img src="notexist.gif" width="100" height="100"><br />
            Quantity: <input type='number' size='3' id='numberinput' name='mynumber' value='0' /></span>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

All my tries did not work. Maybe I am on the wrong path at all. How can I solve this challenge?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a "float: left" to your .box class, so, the boxes in one line, will be adjusted to the screen size.

CSS:

```
.box{
     float: left;
}
```

I implemented your example, with the "float: left" here:

https://jsfiddle.net/dyao1dxm/

Is this your question?